# MVC4 Google Chrome url

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, url, asp.net-mvc-4

In may application I use ajax url for examples as:

```
 url: '/Home/wlMulti',
```

I get this error in Google Chrome:

```
uncaught typeerror property 'location' of object object global is not a function
```

Any idea!! Shour I use ~/Home/..
Would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Where do you get that error? It has nothing to do with that line.  Use the debugger.

Comment: I use Google Developer tool console.  The application works great on IE 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acutall the problem was with

```
window.location("/Home/...");
```

change it to

```
window.location.href = "/Home/....";
```